# Explain verse 3:112 about the people of the Book

Tags: quran

> You are the best community ever raised for humanity—you encourage
> good, forbid evil, and believe in Allah. Had the People of the Book
> believed, it would have been better for them. Some of them are
> faithful, but most are rebellious.
>
> They can never inflict harm on you, except a little annoyance. But if
> they meet you in battle, they will flee and they will have no helpers.
>
> They will be stricken with disgrace wherever they go, unless they are
> protected by a covenant with Allah or a treaty with the people. They
> have invited the displeasure of Allah and have been branded with
> misery for rejecting Allah’s revelations and murdering ˹His˺ prophets
> unjustly. This is ˹a fair reward˺ for their disobedience and
> violations. 3:110-112

Does verse 3:112 mean that Jews and Christians (the people of the Book) will be poor and in disgrace forever? But why do many Jews and Christians today own huge wealth, such as many Americans or many Europeans? And what is meant by "shame"? After all, there are a lot of Christians and they are not under disgrace and many of them are not protected by a covenant with the people of the world. For example, the majority of the population of North and South America are Christians, and they are protected only by their countries, and not by the rest of the world. And who is meant by "people" in this verse?

Please explain the verse 3:112.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some different interpretations of this verse, but this is one of the interpretations.

Allah says: **⟪They⟫** i.e. the Jews since the context is talking about them specifically from the People of the Book **⟪have been put under humiliation [by Allah]⟫** and this humiliation is that they are not left in peace but are fought **⟪wherever they are overtaken⟫** i.e. found or conquered, **⟪except for a covenant from Allah⟫** i.e. the Jizyah from the Muslims **⟪and a rope from the people⟫** i.e. the Christians and other religions helping them or giving them peace treaties.

In summary, Allah says they were punished by being unable to find support, power, or safety on earth except by the Muslims or other nations giving them peace.

As for the existence of their country today, one can say that is because of the rope the people gave to them, especially countries like the US. One can also say this was their general state in the world throughout history since their rejection of the prophets, and an exception for some decades near the end of times does not falsify the general statement. A general rule does not exclude the possibility of exceptions.

Then, Allah says: **⟪And they have drawn upon themselves anger from Allah and have been put under destitution⟫** i.e. poverty and fearing it all the time.

This is not dissimilar to what Allah says about disbelievers in general:

> And whoever turns away from My remembrance - indeed, he will have a depressed life, and We will gather him on the Day of Resurrection blind." (20:124)

It means they will live in fear of poverty or in poverty throughout their life because they are so concerned over the world. On the other hand, the Muslims live in peace and trust in the destiny of Allah and hope of the hereafter.

And then Allah mentions the reason for all this humiliation and punishment: **⟪That is because they disbelieved in the verses of Allah and killed the prophets without right. That is because they disobeyed and [habitually] transgressed.⟫**

And Allah knows best.